# set image in j2me

Tags: java-me, sprite, midp

I'm developing a game in j2me. I'm using one sprite for 4 set of images and changing the images for the sprite accordingly by using [`sprite.setImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/Sprite.html#setImage%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Image,%20int,%20int%29). I'm setting images randomly to sprite during run time.

How to know which image is being used by the sprite during run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: you cannot and probably shouldn't.

Long version: Two common patterns (I would use them both at once) are:

- Always use one image for all the sprites (and tiles, and everything else). Then modify sprite by changing it's frame or frame sequence;
- apply the basic Model / View separation. Don't treat your view (sprite) as a source of knowledge about state of your game, consider it a write-only resource. The state of the game lives in some model class that knows well (perhaps on a more abstracted level) which image was set to which sprite. Such approach will solve more problems, some of which are hard to perceive before they happen (such as the difference between logical and physical location of the sprite in case you have any animation happening upon losing a life, etc).

Comment: if the no.of frames are same in all the images.how to differentiate betweeen the images used for single sprite?

Comment: @Andy: As in the short version of my answer: you can't. Sprites are mostly write only (AND IT IS GOOD). Either fight it (by managing frames by yourself) or embrace it, by building a proper model. Or go around, by building a Hashtable indexed by Sprites with Images in it. Building the model is something that you will not be able to avoid, unless your game is pong, so it's the only solution that does not suck in the long run.